# Добавление данных в начало Таблицы

Tags: google-apps-script

При копировании данных скриптом данные вставляются в низ Таблицы.

```
if(newArch[0])
  archsh.getRange(
    archsh.getLastRow() + 1,
    1,
    newArch.length,
    newArch[0].length
  ).setValues(newArch);
```

Как сделать, что бы данные вставлялись в начало Таблицы начиная с 3й строки?

[Пример Таблицы](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MmCSxakDo5L1ojZZoxL-fHlmqlaL_u3jKcr9lfgT3GM/edit?usp=sharing) К сожалению методы, указанные в справке и по ссылкам, не помогли.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам необходимо сначала [добавить строки](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertRowsBefore(Integer,Integer)), а потом записать в них данные.
Перепишите ваш код следующим образом

```
if(newArch[0])
  prependData_(archsh, null, newArch);
```

Добавьте функцию

```
function prependData_(sheet, beforePosition, values){
  beforePosition = beforePosition || (sheet.getFrozenRows() + 1);
  sheet
  .insertRowsBefore(beforePosition, values.length)
  .getRange(beforePosition, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

На всякий случай, если придется добавлять данные снизу

```
...  
  if(newArch[0])
    appendData_(archsh, newArch);
...

function appendData_(sheet, values){
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, 
  values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

Изначальная постановка вопроса [тут](https://plus.google.com/112804310613313018426/posts/H9he88R8AhB).

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!